# Entity Framework 6 multiple savechanges transaction with foreign key constraint

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have the following code in a controller. I'm trying to batch update the database but am getting the folliwing error message:

The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint.

```
using (var context = new EFDbContext())
{
    using (var dbContextTransaction = context.Database.BeginTransaction())
    {
        try
        {
            // MessageThread
            context.MessageThreads.Add(messageThread);
            context.SaveChanges();                            

            // Message
            context.Messages.Add(message);
            context.SaveChanges();

            // Recipient
            context.Recipients.Add(recipient);
            context.SaveChanges();

            dbContextTransaction.Commit();
        }   
        catch //(Exception ex)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Something went wrong. Please try again.");

            return View("Message", model);

            // dbContextTransaction.Rollback(); no need to call this manually.
        }
    }   
}
```

The Message class has following property:

```
[ForeignKey("MessageThread")]
public long MessageThreadID { get; set; } // ID
public virtual MessageThread MessageThread { get; set; }
```

I can't add a Message because MessageThreadID there is a foreign key constraint on MessageThread. But I can't save them one at a time, this needs to be done in one transaction for data integrity.

How do I do this in one go? Perhaps could I temporarily disable the foreign key constraint?

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a 1:n relationship of `Messge` to `MessageThread`.
Therefore, you should have a collection of `MessageThread` on `Message`, for example

```
public virtual List<MessageThread> MessageThreads {get;set;}
```

If you want to add a `MessageThread` to the `Message` in the same transaction, you should add it to that list.

If you have automatic change tracking active (which it is by default), EntityFramework automatically notices that an entity was added to `Message` and puts it in the current context.
So when you invoke `SaveChanges`, both should be saved in one transaction.

Answer (score 0):

Is your object message contains a messageThread object in his properties ? Maybe you can just insert your object Message, who contains your object MessageThread ?

Something like that :

```
using (var context = new EFDbContext())
{
    using (var dbContextTransaction = context.Database.BeginTransaction())
    {
        try
        {
            message.MessageThread = messageThread;

            // Message
            context.Messages.Add(message);
            context.SaveChanges();

            // Recipient
            context.Recipients.Add(recipient);
            context.SaveChanges();

            dbContextTransaction.Commit();
        }   
        catch //(Exception ex)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Something went wrong. Please try again.");

            return View("Message", model);

            // dbContextTransaction.Rollback(); no need to call this manually.
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: That won't work. I need a general solution anyway because a property of Recipient, namely MessageID, has a FK relationship to Message, just as MessageThreadID in Message has a FK relationship to MessageThread. This needs to be done in one batch.

Answer (score 0):

I was creating the objects to be saved outside of the scope of the transaction. So I created three objects in a row before the transaction block. Like this:

```
MessageThread messageThread = new MessageThread();
Message message = new Message
{
    Subject = model.Subject,
    MessageText = model.MessageText,
    DateSent = DateTime.UtcNow,
    SenderID = sender.Id,
    MessageThreadID = messageThread.MessageThreadID
};
etc.
```

No wonder it wasn't working. I'm an idiot. It was a refactoring error. This works:

```
using (var context = new EFDbContext())
{
    using (var dbContextTransaction = context.Database.BeginTransaction())
    {
        try
        {
            // MessageThread
            MessageThread messageThread = new MessageThread();
            context.MessageThreads.Add(messageThread);
            context.SaveChanges();

            // Message
            Message message = new Message
            {
                Subject = model.Subject,
                MessageText = model.MessageText,
                DateSent = DateTime.UtcNow,
                SenderID = sender.Id,
                MessageThreadID = messageThread.MessageThreadID
            };
            context.Messages.Add(message);
            context.SaveChanges();

            etc.
```